# Access function inside CDATA

Tags: javascript

I have the following code in my ASP.net application js:

```
//<![CDATA[

function GetQuestionErrors() 
{
//Some code 
}
var myclientvariable=null;
//]]>

function calValue()
{
var data=GetQuestionErrors();//Registered function in code behind C#
}
```

When control comes to  `var data=GetQuestionErrors();` it throws an error 'Object expected'. Please assist me to solve this issue.

Comment: The CDATA stuff (the notation, not the code **in** the CDATA) means nothing whatsoever to the Javascript interpreter; in fact it won't even see it. Show the code to that "GetQuestionErrors" function because that's where the error is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Commented CDATA tags inside script tags hasn't been needed since netscape 1.
For ASP pages, they might be required though, but more like this:

```
<![CDATA[
<script>
    // code
</script>
]]>
```

Or equivalent.

In otherwords, the JavaScript does not need to be escape in JavaScript runtime.